# Check whether the input is the largest 2's complement integer

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

```
/*
 * isTmax - returns 1 if x is the maximum, two's complement number,
 *     and 0 otherwise 
 *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | +
 *   Max ops: 10
 *   Rating: 1
 */
int isTmax (int x) 
{
    int t = x + 1;
    return !(t + t) ^ !t;
}
```

If `x` is the largest 2's complement number then `2*t` overflows to 0 but its also 0 if `x` is -1 so we xor it with `!t` which evaluates to 1. So we must get 1 but somehow the output is 0.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210477/discussion-on-question-by-raqeeb-khan-check-whether-the-input-is-the-largest-2s).

Answer (score 2):

This code is fundamentally wrong. Signed overflow is undefined behavior and not guaranteed to give any form of deterministic result.

To check if a number is the "largest possible", you would rather compare it with `INT_MAX` from limits.h. Or if you will, compare it with `(int) ((1u<<31)-1)`.

Comment: Only these operators are allowed !, ~, &, ^, |, +.

Comment: @raqeebkhan Why the restriction to "!, ~, &, ^, |, +. –".  Hopefully not a programming course.

Comment: No, its from a book(Computer systems: A programmers perspective) i'm following to teach myself systems programming.

Comment: @raqeebkhan Ok so instead of ==, write some dumb thing like `return !(INT_MAX - x);`. Congratulations, you made the code an unreadable mess and gained nothing but increased bug potential.

Comment: @raqeebkhan It is good to improve your knowledge, but a lesson of how to use C incorrectly (rely on undefined behavior) is not a good systems programming lesson. Consider another book and good luck.

Answer (score -1):

```
int isTmax (int x) {
    return !(~(x + x + 1) | !(~x));
}
```

This works as (x+x+1) becomes -1 if x is INT_MAX  and all that's left is to check if x is not -1.

Comment: it is Undefined Behaviour if the the integer overflows. It can be -1 but it can be also any other number

Answer (score -1):

If  constants are allowed, you can do

```
int isTmax (int x) 
{
   return !(((unsigned) x) ^ 0x7fffffff);
}
```

Otherwise, you can do

```
int isTmax (int x) 
{
unsigned nx = ~(unsigned) x;
unsigned r = !(nx + nx) ^ !nx;
}
```